# Nodejs MongoDB, findOneAndUpdate is not updating any data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update my mongodb Data with `findOneAndUpdate()`. Its not returning any error. Error is `null`. But its not also updating any data. In the console I am getting this message:

```
Mongoose: datas._findAndModify({ _id: undefined }, [], { '$set': { note: undefined, date: undefined, title: undefined }
```

My Schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var note = new Schema({
    title:String,
    date:String,
    note:String
})

const Data = mongoose.model("Data", note)

module.exports = Data
```

Server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var app = express()
var Data = require('./notesSchema')


mongoose.connect('mongoDB://localhost/newDB',{
    
  })
mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("connected to DB!")
}).on("error", (error)=>{
    console.log("failed to connect" + error)
})
app.get("/hi", (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hello World.")
})
// Create a NOTE
app.post("/create", (req, res)=> {
    var note = new Data({
        note: req.get("note"),
        titile: req.get("title"),
        date: req.get("date"),
    })
    note.save().then(() => {
        if(note.isNew == false){
            console.log("Saved data!")
            res.json({response: "ok"});
        }else{
            console.log("Failed to save data")
        }
    })
})

// http://192.168.0.102:8081/create
var server = app.listen(8081, "192.168.0.102", ()=>{
    console.log("server is running")
})


mongoose.set('debug', true)

// update a Note
app.post("/update", (req,res)=>{
    Data.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: req.get("id")
    }, {
        title: req.get("title"),
        date: req.get("date"),
        note: req.get("note"),
    },{new: true},(err)=>{
        console.log("failed to update  " + err)
    })
    res.send("Updated")
})


// fetch all Notes
app.get("/fetch", (req,res)=>{
    Data.find({}).then((DBitems) => { 
        res.send(DBitems)
    })
})

// Delete a Note
app.post("/delete", (req,res) =>{
    Data.findOneAndRemove({
        _id : req.get("id")
    },(err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: @tranvirgeek : before passing data into the query, console.log all three variables are comes into the req.get.

Comment: The params value come into the body, try req.body.title or req.body.data if you are passing params into json(raw) params

Comment: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined, I am getting this error now.

Comment: could you please let me know where you are passing your input parameters

Comment: Through Postman.

Comment: Yes but in postman where with route or in body or in form data where ?

Comment: I was sending data from params, now sending data from header, working.

Answer (score 2):

Your id may be null. Request have *params* as @AdhamLucasdaSilvaOliveira says.

```
app.post('/update:id', (req, res) => {
    Data.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': req.params.id, {dataset} })
})
```

if req.get('title') is null try to use **req.body.title**

Answer (score 1):

I think that one problem is in the `req.get()` because **request** usually have params and query. So try use `req.query.title` if you pass the title like: `/example?title=cool` or `req.params.title` if you pass the title like: `/example/cool`.

Another problem is in:

```
app.post("/create", (req, res)=> {
    var note = new Data({
        note: req.get("note"),
  ->>>  titile: req.get("title"),
```

Because in your Schema,the second field is named `title` and not `titile`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you are passing your parameters.

```
1) If you pass params in the body with json:

     var note = req.body.note;

2) If you pass params with route like /localhost:3000/update/params(id or note)

      var note = req.params.note
```